# PHP - Alfresco integration

Tags: php, web-services, alfresco

I am currently receiving a Strict Standards error when trying to make an alfresco web service call. I am using the Zend Framework. The tutorial works fine when not using the Zend  Framework.

If i use the Zend_Soap_Client  i get a segmentation error, when i use the PHP Soap_Client i get the following error message:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of AlfrescoWebService::__call() should be compatible with that of SoapClient::__call() in /opt/work/intranet/shamraiza/src/intranet/library/spectrum/Alfresco/AlfrescoWebService.php on line 130
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of AlfrescoWebService::__soapCall() should be compatible with that of SoapClient::__soapCall() in /opt/work/intranet/shamraiza/src/intranet/library/spectrum/Alfresco/AlfrescoWebService.php on line 130

Comment: Can you post the code one line 130

Answer (score 2):

For the first Strict standards, you just have to modify function __call in AlfrescoWebService.php like this

`public function __call($function_name, $arguments)`

$arguments is not optionnal

For the second,

`public function __soapCall($function_name, $arguments=array(), $options=array(), $input_headers= array(), $output_headers=array())`

This must be modify like this

`public function __soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options=array(), $input_headers= array(), &$output_headers=array())`

$arguments still not optionnal

$output_headers passed by reference.